# Convert Quarter + Year to a date

Tags: sql

I have two fields I need to combine and convert to a date. These two fields are i) `Quarter` &
ii) `Year`

For example Q2 2017
01/04/2018

I don't have a field for the day so I just want to keep it to the first of the month.

Please could someone help with the SQL. I need to add to a select statement.

Comment: Year and quarter on _which_ day and time?  Also, which database are you using?

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server you can do this as followed:

First I create a date as varchar which I then convert to the Date datatype. After this I format it to the desired format. I use a CASE Clause to get the correct month by the quarter.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                    CAST(CASE
                         WHEN [Quarter] = 'Q1' THEN '01' 
                         WHEN [Quarter] = 'Q2' THEN '04'
                         WHEN [Quarter] = 'Q3' THEN '07'
                         WHEN [Quarter] = 'Q4' THEN '10' END AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                    CAST('01' AS VARCHAR(2))), 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'en-us')
                    from dates
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SQL SERVER , then you can try something like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(Quarter,
  CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, year), 0))) AS StartOfMonth
FROM Table1;
```

If you need some space in between Quarter and Year then, add `' '`.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(Quarter,' ',
  CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, year), 0))) AS StartOfMonth
FROM Table1;
```